# why am I getting this warning message when adding new columns to dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
tag_df = df[['tag', 'date']]    
tag_df['level'] = ['1'] * len(tag_df)
```

I got a warning message:

```
 SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I then tried:

```
tag_df.loc[:, 'level'] = ['1'] * len(tag_df)
```

But I got the same warning message. What's wrong here?

Comment: tag_df is a copy of a slice. You have at some point _before_ this provided code you have unsafely subset your code. Either `tag_df = df[cols]` or `tag_df = df[mask]` when it should have been `tag_df = df[cols].copy()` or `tag_df = df[mask].copy()`

Comment: The warning is letting you know that `df[mask]['col'] = value` will not work because `df[mask]` produces a copy and recommends that you use `df.loc[mask, 'col'] = value` but that message is not helpful here.

Comment: @HenryEcker I edited my question. Yes, there is one more line before it. Should I add a copy() function to it after slicing?

Comment: Yes. `tag_df = df[['tag', 'date']].copy()` would resolve the issue.